# Tf session.run: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'map'

Tags: tensorflow

I cannot find any specific to this traceback. Any idea what could produce this. Does this comes from within creating the network or before?

```
line 840, in train
        loss, global_step, param_norm, grad_norm = self.run_train_iter(session, batch, summary_writer)
qa_model.py", line 435, in run_train_iter
        [_, summaries, loss, global_step, param_norm, gradient_norm] = session.run(output_feed, input_feed)
      File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 929, in run
        run_metadata_ptr)
      File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1121, in _run
        np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
      File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 501, in asarray
        return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'map'
```

Comment: There is a problem in the dtype of some argument in any of the methods.

Comment: how can I debug session.run() where at which point in the grah happens this?